# Webpack can't import a .json file when using alias / aliased paths

Tags: json, webpack, webpack-4

I am using Webpack's native json importer to import a json file as a javascript object:

```
import config from "./config.json"
```

Works fine - problem is, when I add an alias to the webpack configuration:

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@data": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/data/"),
    },
  },
```

Importing the json file via the aliased path does not seem to work anymore:

```
import config from "@data/config.json
```

```
ERROR in ...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@alias/file.json' in ...
```

Is there any trick to get Webpack's native json importer to play nice with aliased paths?

Answer (score 0):

for me , I add **"resolveJsonModule": true,** to jsconfig.json. it works for me.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*":[
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to add the [extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions) field to the resolve configuration and include ".json" in the array - after doing that both `import config from "@data/config` (as the extensions is resolved automatically) and `import config from "@data/config.json` seem to work fine.